# Can I get rid of my Premium Raid Passes?

Tags: pokemon-go

I don't do raids often, but I've been buying the event boxes for the cheaper items - The Star Pieces primarily.

However, these all come with Premium Raid Passes. This would normally be fine, but I don't raid very often, and even when I do, the free passes are the only ones that get used, since once I've used it, the very next time I join a raid battle, or visit a PokeStop, I get another free one anyway.

**Edit:** currently, even if I do leave a raid, I am immediately rewarded with another free raid pass.

At this rate, they're just taking up space in my bag. Is there any way I can get rid of them, or even use them?

Comment: react to edit, yes when you left you will get free pass but only once per day, so you can rid them off when you do it more times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now delete them after applying the latest update

Answer (score 8):

**April 2019 Update:**
You can now delete your Raid Passes by simply clicking the 'delete' button.

*Legacy info:*
*There's only one in-game way of deleting those Premium Raid Passes, which is as user SHRLY has suggested - just join an ongoing raid and leave them repeatedly until all is used up.*

*Alternatively, you can also email Niantic support and ask to remove your Premium Raid Passes (as well as other non-deletable items like Incubators), by going to [the Niantic support page](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008306667) and selecting "Purchase Issues".*

Comment: @Ben Here's you go, under "Purchase Issues": https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008306667

Comment: @Ben Purchase Issues.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I had same problem, they can not be deleted. I join raid left raid, join raid left raid,... that is only way how to rid them off.

Comment: If you wait in the lobby until the last seconds, then rejoin the raid (and fail to beat the boss) you will be "rewarded" with a nominal amount of stardust, so you can at least get a bit more than 0 out of the disposal.